# GRDB framework is causing crashes in TestFlight: How do I correct this situaton?

Tags: ios, swift, app-store, grdb

I have a project that runs perfectly in Simulation, and on physical devices. It uses a Framework that I created that provides game logic. Originally this framework contained a framework that accesses sqlite, GRDB. This seemed to cause problems, because the App Store validation won't allow that nesting.

So, I moved GRDB to the same hierarchical level as the Game, and to get them communicating, my solution was to make the a GRDB instance in the main viewController a delegate for the Game. I don't mind this, in some ways it improves the structure of the app.

But I cannot get the app to integrate GRDB, and the clue seems to be in this, which is the file arrangement of the project:

[image: file arrangement]

Those red items have got to be the problem, but I don't know how to configure thing to sort it out. The documentation is opaque to me, but I can figure out that these items are not local to the project. Selecting the individual red GRDB framework files shows that they are for non-iOS targets, and this is an only iOS project. This is also heading for production, so I don't need the tests either.

Where is this configured? Or am I on the wrong track? When I run the project via TestFlight, it crashes on my iOS devices, whenever I instantiate the GRDB framework, on startup, and I have sent crash reports but none show up in the Organizer.

Comment: Hello, what about updating the question so that the "crash" is made explicit (eventual message, code, stack trace, etc.) Without such information, it's difficult to understand what's wrong in your app.

Comment: Hi Gwendal, I would, but there are no crashes locally, and when it crashes in TestFlight, before it launches I get an "app crashed" message, but no logging messages appear. I'm making more progress with CoreData at the moment, and I'm probably going to convert the app to use that.

Comment: All right! Happy Core Data!